# How to prevent system alert for IOS push notification

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have an application that receives push notifications for nice place near you.

Imagine that the user is near particular place and web service store position, if one sec. after the mobile phone loses connection for 1 hour, and user continues moving, one hour later, when connection comes back, I will receive an alert for push notification that is still not valid, is there a way to test the payload and prevent alert if notification is not valid?

Comment: push notification is system handle...i dont think u can stop it if you already sent

Comment: I think you need to manage the condition based on the pay load. Suppose you are reached the destination, then you must check the pay load that whether the content is for the location you reached already, if so you wont show it.

Comment: You can use a silent push (content-available:1) and then post a local notification if is still applicable

Comment: Yes, it'a a good idea, but if i use content-available 1, can my app be relaunch if user has been killed? like in the significantLocationChange?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the `apns-expiration` value when sending your notification.

> A UNIX epoch date expressed in seconds (UTC). This header identifies the date when the notification is no longer valid and can be discarded.
>   If this value is nonzero, APNs stores the notification and tries to deliver it at least once, repeating the attempt as needed if it is unable to deliver the notification the first time. If the value is 0, APNs treats the notification as if it expires immediately and does not store the notification or attempt to redeliver it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html

If you still want a silent notification - you can send one without that header.